# how to replace a filepicker file using request?

Tags: node.js, pdf, filepicker.io

I have a filepicker url of a pdf file.  I need to replace that pdf file, with another pdf file, while keeping that same url in nodejs.

I have a base64 string of the pdf that I want to send to filepicker.  I know I have to do some type of post request (preferably using the request module), but not really sure how to execute this.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Below is the request, but the pdf is being saved as a corrupted file in filepicker.  I don't think I've set up my request object correctly for a base64 pdf.  I am getting the string from pdfunite, which is working correctly because I've tried emailing it as an attachment and it shows up correctly.

```
    request.post({url: 'https://www.hypdf.com/pdfunite', encoding: null, formData: formData}, function(err, res3, body3){
        console.log(res3.statusCode);
        console.log(err);
        dpdf = body3.toString('base64');  //this is the pdf I want to send to filepicker

        var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: dpdf,
        url: FILEPICKER_URL,
        headers: [
          {
            name: 'content-type',
            value: 'application/pdf'
          }
        ]
      };

      request(options, function(err, httpResponse, body){ 
        console.log('body: ', body);
        console.log('code ', httpResponse.statusCode)
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overwrite existing filepicker file send POST request with file url and data payload.

This is basic node.js example for text file, should be similar for pdf.

```
var request = require('request');

var existedFileUrl = 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/9jUqfXmSoWZiTN4Zcq9H';

request(existedFileUrl, function (error, response, body) {

    console.log('Original content: ', body);

    var input = process.argv[2] || 'new_text';

    var options = {
      method: 'post',
      body: input,
      // append base64decode option for base64 string
      url: existedFileUrl + '?base64decode=true'
    };

    request(options, function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
        console.log('body: ', body);
    });
});
```

Also check out docs https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/rest_api/writing

Comment: Thanks krystiangw!  I've implemented the request, but the pdf being stored is being corrupted.  I don't think I'm setting up the request object correctly for a pdf.  It is not a file, it is a base64 string which is a pdf.  I've updated the question accordingly.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I edited my post. base64decode=true option should works.

Comment: Works! Thanks krystiangw!